# Arduino Uno R3 not recognized by computer, TX and RX not blinking, neither are lit. Is it dead?

Tags: arduino-uno, atmega328

I was trying to make my arduino uno r3 to work on my Linux machine (including the IDE), but it wouldn't. At first I thought it was a software problem. Added myself to different groups and did everything, people discussed on the forums. It didn't work. It wasn't recognized by the computer at all. I reinstalled. Nothing again. Thought it was a hardware problem of my computer. Tried with dad's (Windows 7 machine). Didn't work. Then I saw that the two leds (TX and RX) are not blinking, neither are lit. I started doing a research on the internet but everybody suggests doing the loopback test from the IDE. My Arduino Uno R3 is not recognized by the computer, therefore the IDE. Is there any way to check if it's dead or if it's a minor problem?

Edit: I read a lot on the case last night and I reach to the conclusion that my ATmega16u2 (the usb-serial chip, I'm sure it is 16u2 and not 8u2, it's written on the chip itself) might be dead. Tried to reflash the firmware but cannot get it in DFU mode (as it says in this article [click here](http://arduino.cc/en/Hacking/DFUProgramming8U2)). dfu-programmer (the Linux application) throws the following error: `dfu-programmer: no device present`. What to do?

Comment: Have you tried seeing if a programmer can talk to the two MCUs?

Comment: Pretty new to electrical engineering, what does MCU stands for. Google gives too much results.

Comment: "Microcontroller unit", or just "microcontroller" for short.

Comment: Ok, but how to check if the programmer can talk to the MCUs?

Comment: Hook it up and run the programmer software, and try to read something from them.

Answer (score 1):

There is a chance that your bootloader is not working anymore. You can burn a new bootloader to the device with another Uno, there are nice [guides on the Arduino-Website](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard).

Answer (score 0):

Before you can access serial TX/RX on Arduino make sure USB to serial converter on the board is working. To check it (on Linux) do the following:

1. Open the terminal, type 'dmesg' and press 'enter'. You will see some output with timestamps (number in square brackets). Note the timestamp of the last line. Run dmesg several times to make sure nothing writes to it and you still see the last timestamp.
2. Plug your board into USB port and run dmesg once again. You should see something like the output below. The first line is the last line of dmesg prior to plugging in the Arduino, the second line is actual detection. The board I used in this example is 2560, UNO will give you similar output. If you can see this output your board is recognized just fine. If you can't see it then either the USB to serial chip (just another AVR MCU) on the Arduino or USB host in your PC or both are defective.

```
    [279152.351690] systemd-logind[867]: New session c51 of user lightdm.
    [280362.732094] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using uhci_hcd
    [280362.931266] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=2341, idProduct=0010
    [280362.931275] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=220
    [280362.931282] usb 3-2: Product: Arduino Mega 2560
    [280362.931288] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Arduino (www.arduino.cc)
    [280362.931293] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 64938323331351213172
    [280362.986579] cdc_acm 3-2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
    [280362.988470] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
    [280362.988473] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
    [280362.732094] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 3 using uhci_hcd
    [280362.931266] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=2341, idProduct=0010
    [280362.931275] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=220
    [280362.931282] usb 3-2: Product: Arduino Mega 2560
    [280362.931288] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: Arduino (www.arduino.cc)
    [280362.931293] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: 64938323331351213172
    [280362.986579] cdc_acm 3-2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
    [280362.988470] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
    [280362.988473] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
```

Comment: `dmesg` isn't changing it's output at all. `lsusb` doesn't detect it also. `/dev/ttyACM0` or `/dev/ttyUSB0` are not created.

Comment: If you need an answer to a question which part of my answer answers your question then please ask another question.

Comment: What? Why? Your answer doesn't answer my question, it just starts a series of "Do this!" and "Doesn't work comments".

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete your Arduino IDE, but store your libraries if you need in future.
2. Download Arduino ERW 1.0.5 from here: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=118440
3. Try your steps again with your connections belong to your schematic.

Comment: The hardware doesn't work on two independent machines and you're blaming the software?

Comment: Did the other PC has Arduino IDE or Arduino ERW? I guess, it was Arduino IDE not ERW. Shall we try ERW? If not, I will be in silence.

Comment: Arduino ERW is only for Windows and I use Linux. For now, I don't have a Windows PC around me, but even if I had, I need to make it work under Linux. I understand that, at least I will find out if the Arduino board is broken, but...